# After moving folders the key in unity doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

Yesterday moved folders with the project to unity and now I have to enter the password for the Alias, I will be very happy if you can help solve this issue. The password is exactly correct.

[image: keystore menu]

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is.

Comment: I can't compile a project without the alliance password.

Comment: If you haven't already released it on Google Play, you can just create a new keystore. The Alias password should stay the same, if you created the keystore, then you should know what the password is. (Unless you forgot, which I completely sympathize with)

Comment: I realized I changed the 2017 version of unity to 2019 and because of this, the key doesn't fit

Answer (score 1):

If you're not releasing your app on Google Play then you can untick "Custom Keystore", your app will be signed with default debug key.

But if you want to sign it with your own key then if you're doing it for the first time you need to go to the keystore manager and add your own Alias (probably that is what you meant by "alliance"). If you have added your Alias already and it's not showing up then you have selected wrong keystore or provided wrong password.

Comment: I realized I changed the 2017 version of unity to 2019 and because of this, the key doesn't fit